# How to number every <dt> on my <dl> or use bullets to list them

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I use numbers or bullets to list each dt on my description list? I tried to but couldn't. I would have used ol but I needed to describe each item(dt) on my dl.

Is it possible to number or use bullets to list my dt on dl, or would I always have the list display without numbers/bullets no matter what?

The dl I have been trying to number it's dt, see image:

Check:

```
<dl type="number">
<dt>First Item</dt>
<dd>The description of the first item</dd>
<dt>Second Item</dt>
<dd>Description of the second item</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Please no pictures of code. Copy/write your code here, so others can testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answers aren't wrong, but then the question is actually a html code related.
Here is what I figured out and it worked:

```
<dl>
    <span>&#8226;Apple</span>
    <dd>He like eating at least apples daily</dd>
    <span>&#8226;Orange Juice</span>
    <dd>This is the description of the second dt</dd>
</dl>
```

Or more correctly:

```
<dl>
    <dt>&#8226;First Item</dt>
    <dd>This is the description of the first item </dd>
    <dt>&#8226;Second Item</dt>
    <dd>This is the description of the second item</dd>
</dl>
```

Different types of symbols:
https://www.htmlsymbols.xyz/unicode/U+2022

Answer (score 0):

display - make the item behave like an item inside a list

style-type - will set the bullet point

stype-position - will make it so that your element starts from the bullet point

```
dt{
  display: list-item;
  list-style-type: disc;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dt::before{
    content: '\2022';
    margin: 0 5px
}
```

or

```
dt{
    display: list-item;
    list-style-type: disc;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

different types [symbols](https://www.htmlsymbols.xyz/unicode/U+2022)